# Filtering an object with multiple filter values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object which which has three different arrays like location vertical and roundType, and i will get a filter object that will have the same three arrays in that object. This is data that needs to be filtered

```
testObject = [{
    "id": 1892928,
    "vertical_tax": [
      678,
      664
    ],
    "location_tax": [
      666
    ],
    "roundType": [
      "rt1"
    ],
}
{
    "id": 1892927,
    "vertical_tax": [
      662,
      663
    ],
    "location_tax": [
       663
    ],
    "roundType": [
      "rt2"
    ],
}]
```

This is the filter object based on which the filtering should happen

```
 filterObject = {
    locations: [666,667]
    roundTypes: ["rt1","rt2"]
    verticals: [662,661]
   }
```

Original requirements : was to get any of objects with a particular value in either of the filter object arrays. This could be done with use of "some".
Update requirements : So i need to filter the main object with the values passed in the filterObject. So all the conditions in filterObject should be matched. All the ids that match should be returned. this can be done with "every"

Comment: Can you reframe the question ?

Comment: So i need to filter the main object with the values passed in the filterObject. So it would be like if filterobject has location:[666,667] then in the main object all those ids which contain 666 in their location array should be returned

Comment: This would be simpler is the properties matched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter on the objects and just exclude them.  I've commented out part of the comparisons, because it's not clear if you want to filter on those properties, and how.  You only mentioned locations.  If you want it to include all matching results for all the properties, change the `&&` to `||`.
As has been mentioned, the code could be simplified and generalized if the properties matched (or had consistent naming).

`filterObjects` filters on any match being present.
`filterObjects1` requires presence of all elements in `verticals`, and any match in the other properties.

```js
testObject = [{
    "id": 1892928,
    "vertical_tax": [
      678,
      664
    ],
    "location_tax": [
      666
    ],
    "roundType": [
      "rt1"
    ],
},
{
    "id": 1892927,
    "vertical_tax": [
      662,
      663
    ],
    "location_tax": [
       663
    ],
    "roundType": [
      "rt2"
    ],
}]

 filterObject = {
    locations: [666,667],
    roundTypes: ["rt1","rt2"],
    verticals: [662,661]
   };
   
   const filterObjects = (filterObject, testObject) => {
    return testObject.filter(obj => 
      obj.location_tax && obj.location_tax.some(
        x => filterObject.locations && filterObject.locations.includes(x)) ||
      obj.roundType && obj.roundType.some(
        x => filterObject.roundTypes && filterObject.roundTypes.includes(x)) ||
      obj.vertical_tax && obj.vertical_tax.some(
        x => filterObject.verticals && filterObject.verticals.includes(x))
    );
   };
   console.log(filterObjects(filterObject, testObject));


 filterObject = {
    roundTypes: ["rt1","rt2"],
    verticals: [662,661]
 };

   console.log(filterObjects(filterObject, testObject));

   // require presence of all objects in filterObject.verticals using .every
   const filterObjects1 = (filterObject, testObject) => {
    return testObject.filter(obj => 
      (obj.location_tax && obj.location_tax.some(
        x => filterObject.locations && filterObject.locations.includes(x)) ||
       obj.roundType && obj.roundType.some(
        x => filterObject.roundTypes && filterObject.roundTypes.includes(x)) 
      ) &&
      filterObject.verticals.every( x => obj.vertical_tax && obj.vertical_tax.includes(x) )
    );
   };

 filterObject = {
    roundTypes: ["rt1","rt2"],
    verticals: [662,663]
   };
   delete testObject[0].vertical_tax;
  
   console.log(filterObjects1(filterObject, testObject));
```

// *must* match some value in *all* filterObject properties *that exist*

```js
testObject = [{
    "id": 1892928,
    "vertical_tax": [
      678,
      664
    ],
    "location_tax": [
      666
    ],
    "roundType": [
      "rt1"
    ],
},
{
    "id": 1892927,
    "vertical_tax": [
      662,
      663
    ],
    "location_tax": [
       663
    ],
    "roundType": [
      "rt2"
    ],
}]

 filterObject = {
    locations: [666,667],
    roundTypes: ["rt1","rt2"],
//    verticals: [662,661,678]
   };
   
   // _must_ match some value in _all_ filterObject properties _that exist_
   
   const filterObjects = (filterObject, testObject) => {
    return testObject.filter(obj => 
      (!filterObject.locations || obj.location_tax && obj.location_tax.some(
        x => filterObject.locations && filterObject.locations.includes(x))) &&
      (!filterObject.roundTypes || obj.roundType && obj.roundType.some(
        x => filterObject.roundTypes && filterObject.roundTypes.includes(x))) &&
      (!filterObject.verticals || obj.vertical_tax && obj.vertical_tax.some(
        x => filterObject.verticals && filterObject.verticals.includes(x)))
    );
   };
   console.log(filterObjects(filterObject, testObject));
```

Comment: yea it is for all three properties like locations, verticals and roundTypes. One more question what if the one of the property does'nt have a value                                              
  filterObject = {
    locations: [666,667],
    roundTypes: [],
    verticals: [662,661]
   };

Comment: inclusive OR, or they need to match all properties?  as for the properties not having value, will need to add a check to make sure the property is defined, or it depends on how you want it to behave.  if it is null or undefined, you want it to just not filter it at all or what?

Comment: need to match atleast one property.... how to add that check , because get an undefined error

Comment: I've updated the code, you'll see I add a check for each filterObject property.  I didn't add the check for testObject, but it's similar

Comment: okay so one more question what if the results need to have 662 and 663 to be there. Basically all the properties needs to be matched

Comment: you would want to use `filterObject.vertical.every( x => obj.vertical_tax.includes(x) )`, assuming filterObject.vertical is `[662,663]`.  If you need to match on both `OR` and `AND`, you will need to change the structure of the filter object to include that.  If your needs get any more complicated, I highly recommend finding a library that does it for you.  Either something with a LINQ-like interface, and/or a data structure library, or simply just lodash.

Comment: yes filterobject.vertical is [662,663]. Can you just update the code thanks

Comment: Please edit in the different requirements you have into your main question.  That way we can keep this question and answer relevant to future users.

Comment: I have added it as a function named `filterObjects1` at the end of the code

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: I mean to include both the original requirements, and the updated requirement.  This will be helpful for future visitors trying to learn how to use `.every` vs `.some`, and understanding the use of `&&` vs `||` for building comparisons.

Comment: also all the filterobject array values should match that the goal. But i got it. same as vertical i can alter the code, thanks

Comment: One more requirement, so what if i want all the values in the vertical array and roundType array to be matched and instead of || operation I want an && operation between these filters                                                                                                             ```Ex: filterObject = {
    locations: [666,667],
    roundTypes: ["rt1","rt2"],
   }; ```                                                                                                                               so locations[666 || 667 ] && roundTypes["rt1" || "rt2"] . This sums up my question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test only a single criteria, just use that statement and discard the rest, or if you want to have either of the conditions be true to get the result then change the && logic to || for the necessary statements.

```
testObject.filter( i => {
return i.vertical_tax.every((value, index) => value === filterObject.verticals[index]) &&
  i.location_tax.every((value, index) => value === filterObject.locations[index]) && 
i.roundType.every((value, index) => value === filterObject.roundTypes[index]);
});
```

Comment: yea it is for all three properties like locations, verticals and roundTypes. One more question what if the one of the property does'nt have a value filterObject = { locations: [666,667], roundTypes: [], verticals: [662,661] };

Comment: the comparison statements will just skip through that since there is nothing to compare against, there wont be any errors if values are missing